# How to distinguish pts between tty1 and tty7?

Tags: tty

```
ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       830  1.5  1.2 264456 50692 tty7     Ss+  11:38   0:20 /usr/bin/X :0 -
root      2458  0.0  0.0  22320  1968 tty1     Ss+  11:49   0:00 /sbin/agetty --
debian8   2657  0.1  0.1  33528  7480 pts/2    Ss+  11:59   0:00 /bin/bash
debian8   2671  0.4  0.1  33528  7456 pts/3    Ss+  11:59   0:00 /bin/bash
debian8   2682  0.6  0.1  33528  7452 pts/4    Ss+  12:00   0:00 /bin/bash
debian8   2694  1.2  0.1  33528  7432 pts/5    Ss+  12:00   0:00 /bin/bash
root      2703  0.0  0.0  27004  2640 pts/1    R+   12:00   0:00 ps aux
```

Now I want to distinguish pts between tty1 and tty7. How many pts are opened on tty1 and how many pts are opened on tty7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pts` devices are considered virtual. Meaning, they do not have a bound TTY -- instead, they are virtualized through X or SSH.

Therefore, one can safely assume that a `pts` is always on TTY7 (your X session), a Screen session, or an SSH session.

Otherwise, the system has no way of distinguishing what super-process owns a PTS because the system doesn't really care what called a PTS -- it only cares about what's actively using it, as you can see in the `COMMAND` field.